# Private license within copyleft

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing, creative-commons

Within a copyleft license is it possible to have a clause that would grant exclusive rights (=private license) for the same content to a company?

I mean something liky CC-BY-SA plus "company X is being given license to do ...". Is it possible to incorporate this into a single license? Or is it better to incorporate the license for the company within terms of service?

I want to cover that the company will also have "private license" to the derivatives of the content.

EDIT: Learned abozt what "exclusive" rights are and I do not want that. Otherwise the question remains the same.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "exclusive license"? It is *not* the same as a *private* license. A private license can supplement a public license (no problem). An exclusive license would contradict a public license (big problem). Please clarify what sort of license you want to give (or sell) to the company.

Comment: If you give me _exclusive rights_ then you cannot give those rights to anyone else. That's what "exclusive rights" means.

Answer (score 2):

### Think about what a licence is ...

A licence is a contract which basically says “I, the copyright holder, won’t sue you for copyright breach if ...”. The conditions after the “If” can be anything you like.

Clearly, you can give away as many licences on the same or different terms to any number of people. Some people may be covered by more than one licence but so long as they comply with the terms of *any* licence they are immune from your wrath.

However, *you* can only give away **exclusive** rights once - that’s what exclusive means. So for your particular question:

- no, you can’t give one person exclusive rights and then give *anyone* else *any* rights.
- it doesn’t matter if different licences refer to each other or not.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Yes that "private license to company" has to be non-exclusive - I am ok with this. I think most companies like Google, Facebook etc. ask people for non-exclusive rights - this is taken from Spotify: "You grant Spotify a non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free ...". So if I do non-exclusive than everything is ok, right? I mean other people will be able to still use the work commercially adhering to cc-by-sa but the company will have "private license".